# Saving an array as a string after upgrading from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm going through the process of upgrading a Rails project from 3.2.22.5 to 4.0.0 and I've just come across an issue to do with how an array is saved in the database between the two versions.

I have this create action in a controller

```
def create
  entry = current_user.tdr_entries.create()
  entry.update_attributes(params[:tdr_entry])
  if entry.save
    result = 'ok'
  end
  render text: result || 'fail'
end
```

The params are passing values like the following

```
{"tdr_entry"=>{"value"=>["Eyes", "Hair", "Blood", "", "", ""], "multi"=>"true"}}
```

In rails 3.2, value saves to the database with no problem and looks like this from a console:

```
=> "---\n- Eyes\n- Hair\n- Blood\n- ''\n- ''\n- ''\n"
```

But after upgrading to Rails 4, it's throwing an error when trying to do the same thing.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TypeError: can't cast Array to text:
```

How can I to convert the array to a string that is in the same format as it was before in Rails 3.2?

Is it possible to do this? or do I need to completely refactor how this works in rails 4 and serialize it?

Cheers.

Comment: Which database do you use? BTW, that `"---\n..."` stuff looks like the YAML form of an array.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you most of the way there:

```
>> hash = {"tdr_entry" => {"value" => ["Eyes", "Hair", "Blood", "", "", ""], "multi" => "true"}}
>> hash['tdr_entry'].transform_values { |set| Array.wrap(set).join("\n- ") }
=> {"value"=>"Eyes\n- Hair\n- Blood\n- \n- \n- ", "multi"=>"true"}
```

Comment: `["Eyes", "Hair", "Blood", "", "", ""].to_yaml` in the Rails console might be enlightening.